# Adjusting payments against balances some id wise

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have total payments in hand for `Store_ID`s in a table and need to settle/adjust payments against `transactions_id`s for respective `store_id`s.

Tables can be created as follow:

```sql
--- CREATE STORE_PAYMENTS TABLE--- CONTAINS RECEIVABLE AGAINST RECEIPTS NOS FOR STROES-------
CREATE TABLE DBO.STORE_PAYMENTS
 (STORE_ID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
 RECEIPT_NO VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
 RECEIVABLE INT NOT NULL,
 PAYMENT_ADJUSTED INT NOT NULL,
 BALANCE INT NOT NULL)
 GO

INSERT INTO DBO.STORE_PAYMENTS
(STORE_ID,RECEIPT_NO,RECEIVABLE,PAYMENT_ADJUSTED,BALANCE)
VALUES
('STR1',1,100,0,0),
('STR1',2,200,0,0),
('STR1',3,300,0,0),
('STR2',1,100,0,0),
('STR2',2,100,0,0),
('STR2',3,50,0,0),
('STR3',1,0,0,0),
('STR3',2,150,0,0),
('STR3',3,300,0,0)

---- CREATE STORE_BALANCE TABLE --- CONTAINS INFORMATION OF IN HAND PAYMENTS -----------------
CREATE TABLE DBO.STORE_BALANCE
 (STORE_ID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
 PAYMENTS INT NOT NULL)
 GO
   
INSERT INTO DBO.STORE_BALANCE
(STORE_ID,PAYMENTS)
VALUES
('STR1',600),
('STR2',700),
('STR3',300)

SELECT * FROM DBO.STORE_BALANCE
SELECT * FROM DBO.STORE_PAYMENTS
```

The sequence of adjusting payment might be on the basis of RECEIPT_NO order or rowid.

Required Output in Highlighted Columns:

[image]

Comment: Sharing the sample data as DDL + DML is great, but you should also explain the logic of the desired output, and also show what you have already tried.

Comment: why did str2 pay 700 on a 250 bill?

Comment: Dear Zohar, i tried to apply FIFO method used in accounting in SQL but that was too complex for this problem.

Comment: STR1,STR2... are ids assigned to different stores which might have accumulated payments till a specific point of time. Payments might be less then total outstanding amounts or may be more then outstanding (against multiple invoices). At a point, we need to adjust payments against unpaid invoices/receipts. We have to close as many as receipts against available payments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BEGIN TRAN

 --CREATE #STORE_PAYMENTS TABLE--- CONTAINS RECEIVABLE AGAINST RECEIPTS NOS FOR STROES------- 
 CREATE TABLE #STORE_PAYMENTS (STORE_ID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, RECEIPT_NO VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, RECEIVABLE INT NOT NULL, PAYMENTS INT NOT NULL, BALANCE INT NOT NULL)
  GO

INSERT INTO #STORE_PAYMENTS (STORE_ID,RECEIPT_NO,RECEIVABLE,PAYMENTS,BALANCE)
SELECT 'STR1',1,100,0,0  UNION ALL
SELECT 'STR1',2,200,0,0  UNION ALL
SELECT 'STR1',3,300,0,0  UNION ALL
SELECT 'STR2',1,200,0,0  UNION ALL
SELECT 'STR2',2,300,0,0  UNION ALL
SELECT 'STR2',3,400,0,0  UNION ALL
SELECT 'STR3',1,0,0,0 UNION ALL
SELECT 'STR3',2,150,0,0 UNION ALL
SELECT'STR3',3,300,0,0

--CREATE STORE_BALANCE TABLE --- CONTAINS INFORMATION OF IN HAND PAYMENTS ----------------- 

CREATE TABLE #STORE_BALANCE (STORE_ID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, PAYMENTS INT NOT NULL,TMP_PAYMENTS INT NOT NULL) 

INSERT INTO #STORE_BALANCE 
SELECT 'STR1',500,500 UNION ALL
SELECT 'STR2',700,700 UNION ALL
SELECT 'STR3',300,300

SELECT  ROW_NUMBER()Over(Order by Store_ID)RowNum,* INTO #T FROM #STORE_BALANCE --Order by RowNum desc
SELECT DENSE_RANK()OVER(Order by STORE_ID)RANK, ROW_NUMBER()Over(Order by Store_ID)RowNum, * INTO #TT FROM #STORE_PAYMENTS

Declare @strt INT ,@End INT
SELECT TOP 1  @strt=RowNum FROM #t
SELECT @End=MAX(RowNum) FROM #t

While @strt<=@End
Begin 
    DECLARE @RANK INT=1,@Rownum INT,@Payments INT,@RECEIVABLE INT,@Total_RECEIVABLE  INT
    SELECT  @Rownum=MAX(RECEIPT_NO)FROM #TT WHERE  RANK=@strt

                 WHILE @RANK<=@Rownum
                     BEGIN

                             SELECT @Payments=Tmp_Payments FROM #T WHERE RowNum=@strt
                             SELECT @RECEIVABLE=RECEIVABLE  FROM #TT WHERE RANK=@strt AND RECEIPT_NO =@RANK 

                                 IF @Payments >= @RECEIVABLE
                                         Begin 

                                             UPDATE #TT SET PAYMENTS=@RECEIVABLE  WHERE RANK=@strt AND RECEIPT_NO = @RANK

                                             UPDATE  #T SET TMP_PAYMENTS=@Payments-@RECEIVABLE 
                                                     FROM #t Inner Join #tt ON #t.RowNum=#TT.RANK
                                                     WHERE  RECEIPT_NO=@RANK AND RANK=@strt

                                END ELSE BEGIN

                                                 UPDATE #TT SET PAYMENTS =@Payments WHERE RANK=@strt AND RECEIPT_NO = @RANK

                                                 SELECT @Total_RECEIVABLE=SUM(Payments) FROM #TT WHERE RANK=@strt      

                                                 UPDATE  #T SET TMP_PAYMENTS =  @Total_RECEIVABLE-@Payments
                                                         FROM #t Inner Join #tt ON #t.RowNum=#TT.RANK
                                                         WHERE RANK=@strt AND RECEIPT_NO=@RANK 

                                 END
                                -- Select * from #TT WHERE RANK=@strt AND RECEIPT_NO = @RANK 
                                SET @RANK=@RANK+1
                     END

    SET @strt=@strt+1 
END

    UPDATE #STORE_PAYMENTS SET PAYMENTS=T.PAYMENTS,BALANCE=T.RECEIVABLE-T.PAYMENTS
    FROM #STORE_PAYMENTS S INNER JOIN #TT T ON S.STORE_ID=T.STORE_ID AND S.RECEIPT_NO=T.RECEIPT_NO 

    SELECT * FROM #STORE_PAYMENTS

ROLLBACK TRAN
```

Comment: Thanks Alfaiz, I was stuck in the ways in which it could be done and your solution worked.Your provided answer is clearly understandable also. Thumbs up!